# Licia of Lindeldt will not relocate?

Tags: dark-souls-2

According to many online [resources](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Licia_of_Lindeldt):

> Exhausting her dialogue will see her relocate to Majula,

I have exhausting her dialog, she now repeats the same thing every time I talk to her. But she will not relocate.

Is there some other prerequisite that is needed for her to relocate?

Comment: Exhausted her dialog using the 'Talk' option or just kept going back and talking to her?

Comment: You are exactly right, that was what was happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I was doing it wrong.

She was repeating what she was saying every time we spoke, but I did not notice in the store menu that pops up, there was another *talk* option, when I selected that she said other things. I needed to exhaust those.

Comment: It is a good practice to start doing to *every* NPC you come across as many of them will give you items that can only be obtained through these means.